# Updating wordpress tags for multiple posts via SQL

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Here's what I want to do:

1. Find 10 posts that do not have any tags and whose comment count = 0
2. Tag those 10 posts with a tag "tag_name"

With query_posts, the first part should look something like this I think:

```
<?php
query_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tag' => "",
    'paged' => $paged,
    'comment_count' => '0',
    'posts_per_page' => '10',
)); ?>
```

I have no idea what the second part should look like, but I think the whole thing needs to be in SQL form in order to be able to update the tags for the found posts.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Firstly, query_posts is not the same as WP_Query. Read through this first - https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query. However it seems like you're confusing WP_Query with an SQL query.

Comment: Sorry, yes I was confusing WP_Query with query_posts. That said, I do understand the difference between those and SQL query - I was just offering the query_posts analog as an example of what the first part of my request might look like in the code that I do understand.

Comment: So what's your question exactly.. are you looking for the way to add tags to posts from within a WP_Query loop? How are you defining the tag_name variable? is it in a query string or something?

Comment: Here's what I want to do:

1. Find 10 posts that do not have any tags and whose comment count = 0
2. Tag those 10 posts with a tag "tag_name"

How do I do that with an SQL query/update?

Answer (score 0):

```
$tag_name = 'your tag';

$posts = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'comment_count' => '0',
    'posts_per_page' => '10',
));

if( $posts->have_posts() ): while( $posts->have_posts() ): $posts->the_post();

    wp_set_post_tags( $post->ID, $tag_name );

endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: So this is only the first part of the problem. Once I have queried these posts, I need to add a specific tag to them.

1. Find 10 posts that do not have any tags and whose comment count = 0 2. Tag those 10 posts with a tag "tag_name"

Comment: Correct, that's what the `wp_set_post_tags()` function is for. You loop through those 10 queried posts and set that tag on them.